# How to get all the items from DDB where partition key in list of partition keys?

Tags: java, amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries

I have a DDB table which has partition key (user_id) and sort key(user_timestamp). Now I have list of user_id's and I want to query DDB to get all the entries where partition_key in list of user_id's in Java. I have already java code to get all the users based on the given user_id using `DynamoDBQueryExpression`. There are 2 options as per my knowledge

1. In my case the list has always maximum of 2 elements. So I can call the `.query` 2 times (the same method 2 times).
2. Using `batchLoad`

What is the better option to go with?

or Is there any better way to achieve this in Java?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Also look at [PartiQL](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/ql-reference.html).

Answer (score 0):

DynamoDB does not have complex query language that relational databases or advanced document databases have. It works by performing index scan operations, which are really basic low-level operation in any database.

Unlike traditional query languages, you're in charge for combining the results of these operations. Your client-side code serves both as the query engine and the optimizer.

Under the hood, the expression builder will transform your expression into a call to the Query endpoint of DynamoDB API.

A mandatory parameter to this call is [`KeyConditionExpression`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_Query.html#DDB-Query-request-KeyConditionExpression) (or its predecessor `KeyConditions` which is now deprecated, but serves the same purpose).

One required part of any valid key condition expression is specifying the partitioning key and its exact value:

> You must specify the partition key name and value as an equality condition. You cannot use a non-key attribute in a key condition expression.

This means that no matter how you build your queries, in the end DynamoDB should receive one query for one user, because you have set up `user_id` as a partitioning key on your table.

If you already have client-side code which pulls necessary information for one user, there is nothing wrong with calling this code in a loop for every user in the array.

It might sound counterintuitive if you come from a relational database background, but that's how DynamoDB works.

You might parallelize these calls, just make sure you put some kind of threshold on the parallelization algorithm, so as not to exceed your partitions' capacity.

From Dynamo's perspective, it doesn't really matter whether you write an explicit loop or use `batchLoad` or other helpers that the SDK might offer. Under the hood, they would be just calling `Query` in a some kind of a loop anyway.

Answer (score 0):

This depends on your requirements. You have 3 choices, each of which depends on your needs:

1. `BatchGetItem` (BatchLoad)

For this to work you need to know both the partition key and the sort key. If you know both then this is the best option as you can request up to 100 items in a single request, if you have 2 items per user, with a simple loop you can obtain 50 users information in a single request.

2. `Query`

If the sort key is unknown, then you are forced to use the sort key. If you use async non blocking java V2 then it's probably best that you send an individual request for each user, and then combining the results on the client side.

3. `ExecuteStatement` (PartiQL)

If you're using Java V1 then perhaps PartiQL API can help. Similar to Query, where you only know the partition key, you can pass in up to 50 keys as part of a single request. The requests are executed sequentially on the backend, therefore for latency reasons it makes sense to use this only if you're not using Async calls.